# Trying to get NSUserDefaults key, crash occurs

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm at a loss here, I need to be able to get check if NSUserDefaults returns nil and if it does, give it a default value. if it doesn't I need to be able to load the latest array out of NSUserDefaults but my app keeps on crashing and I have no idea why.

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("imageDataArray") != nil {
        arrayOfImages = userDefaults.objectForKey("imageDataArray") as Array
    }else {
        arrayOfImages = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("imageDataArray") as Array

        var image = UIImage(named: "padlock")!
        arrayOfImages.append(image)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayOfImages, forKey: "imageDataArray")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION crash on run and on the first line

Thanks.

Comment: This is what registered user defaults are for, by the way. Values that are not written to disk and are supplied only if real values haven't been supplied.

Comment: Unlike in Objective-C, you don't need to `synchronize()` in Swift.

Comment: The instruction in first line looks correct. It should run without problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first comparison should be `== nil`.
2. I'm not sure you can save a `UIImage` to `NSUserDefaults`.

I think you'd probably like to be a bit more swift-ish about it, too.

```
if let arrayOfImages = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("imageDataArray") {
    var image = UIImage(named: "padlock")!
    arrayOfImages.append(image)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayOfImages, forKey: "imageDataArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
} else {
    // set your default value:
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Array(), forKey: "imageDataArray")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift cares a bit more about typing that objc. You're casting to Array. Try doing it like this. I"m guessing you want arrayOfImages to be an array of UIImage.

```
if let arrayOfImages = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("imageDataArray") as? [UIImage] {
```

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults does not accept inserting directly UIIMage. You should convert to NSData before inserting to NSUserDefaults:

```
 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

To convert back to image:

```
var retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData) //return optional object
```